# VariableSizedGridView Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1** App.

It has **GridView**, First row must show 2 items, 2nd and 3rd row must show 3 items each and rest rows must show 4 items. I am trying to use **VariableSizedGridView**:

[Click Here to View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OozgI.png)

but my items are being shown in 1 column like a long list.

[Click to view ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d5m8.png)

**XAML:**

```
<UserControls:VariableSizedGridView    x:Name="ModelRingsGridViewVariable" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="180" 
        ItemWidth="20" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        <!--ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=modelPage, Path=WidthCalculator}"-->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="White"  Margin="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource LightGreenBlueColor}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">                                   
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" 
                        Text="{Binding ImageName}" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</UserControls:VariableSizedGridView>
```

**C#:**

```
private void GenerateGridViewData()
{
    ModelRingsGridViewVariable.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    ObservableCollection<ModelClass> ModelRingsGridViewData = new ObservableCollection<ModelClass>();
        int j = 1;
        Uri location = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/TestImages/TestImageRing.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        for (int i=0; i<20;i++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i== 1)
            {
                ModelRingsGridViewData.Add(new ModelClass { ImageName = "RING " + j.ToString(), ImageLocation = location, ColSpan=6 });
            }
            else if(i== 2 || i==3 || i==4)
            {
                ModelRingsGridViewData.Add(new ModelClass { ImageName = "RING " + j.ToString(), ImageLocation = location, ColSpan=4 });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelRingsGridViewData.Add(new ModelClass { ImageName = "RING " + j.ToString(), ImageLocation = location,ColSpan=3 });
            }
        j++;
        }
    ModelRingsGridViewVariable.ItemsSource = ModelRingsGridViewData;
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public Uri ImageLocation { get; set; }
    public String ImageName { get; set; }
    public int ColSpan { get; set; }
}
```

**VariableSizedGridView.cs:**

```
 public class VariableSizedGridView : GridView
    {
        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element,
            object item)
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic localItem = item;
               // element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, localItem.RowSpan);
                element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, localItem.ColSpan);
            }
            catch
            {
              //  element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
                element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
            }

            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code is working fine. (https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=775B6FDBA32D0BE2!7114&authkey=!AKdLptuCTEmuNkI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng) the view is as expected